# ngx-sortablejs not working properly for repeated word in angular 8

Tags: angular, sorting, drag-and-drop

I am using ngx-sortablejs version 3.1.3 for my angular project. It's working fine in all cases except the case where we have multiple instance of the same word. When there is 2 instance of same word( e.g. och ) on drag and drop of single word ( och ) cause the dragging of multiple words at the same time. I don't want multiple words to be dragged and dropped at same time.
code:
ts file

```
import { SortablejsOptions } from 'ngx-sortablejs';
options: SortablejsOptions = {
    group:  {
        name : 'test',      
    },
    onAdd: (event: any) => {
        this.sortingfunc();
    },
    onSort: (event: any ) => {
        this.sortingtestfunc();
    },
    swapThreshold: 100,     
};
```

html file

```
<div class="text-jumbled jumbledSentence" [sortablejs]="jumbledSentence" [sortablejsOptions]="options">
     <div class="btn button-text btn-drag" *ngFor="let item of jumbledSentence; let i = index" (click)="addThisWord( $event, item )" (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" data-id="{{i}}-{{item}}">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

How am I to solve this? Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was passing data to jumbledSentence as follows:

```
['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

Now I passed the data as multidimensional array as follows:

```
[
{ index: 0, data: 'data1' },
{ index: 1, data: 'data2' },
{ index: 2, data: 'data3' },
]
```

so that when the data is loaded and sorted id is unique as follows:

```
<div class="btn button-text btn-drag" *ngFor="let item of jumbledSentence; let i = index" (click)="addThisWord( $event, item )" (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" id="{{ item.index }}">
    {{item.data}}
</div>
```